# Как сделать авторизацию в xamarin android через базу данных mysql

Tags: android, c#, mysql, xamarin

Добрый вечер господа. Как сделать авторизацию в xamarin android через базу данных mysql?

вот код собственно:

```
MysqlCommand com = new MysqlCommand("SELECT test_log, test_pass FROM login WHERE test_log =@log AND test_pass =@pass", mycon);
        mycon.Open();
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@log", login1.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", password1.Text);
        MySqlReader dr = com.ExcecuteReader();
```

Я подключил библиотеки, линки и mysqlclient, дальше не соображаю что делать!

Comment: У вас будет прямой доступ к MySql с телефона?

Comment: да это нужно для проекта демонстрации!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если уверены, что будет работать соединение с MySql, то логика может быть такой:

1. Ищете запись по имени пользователя
2. Если не найдена, значит нет пользователя
3. Если найдена, то сверяете пароль.

Иными словами, второй параметр в вашем запросе лишний. Потом проверяете если Reader что-то содержит, если да, то сверяете значение test_pass с тем что задал пользователь.

Comment: Понятно, а как сохранить логин и пароль в xml файле?

Comment: А зачем его сохранять и что за xml файл? И как это относится к авторизации пользователя?

Comment: надо было автоматизироваться без ввода, уже нашли решение. Спасибо за подсказку это помогло!